# Can Schwarz Lemma be reformulated?

Tags: complex-analysis

Taking this straight from Wikipedia.

> [image]

Can this be reformulated to $|f(z) | \geq |z|$ and $|f'(0)| \geq 1$

I was thinking that we could apply Min-Mod principle to $g(z) = \frac{f(z)}{z}$, and let $r \to 1$, but I feel like I overlooked something really obvious.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ vanishes only at the origin with order $1$ and $|f(z)|=1$ when $|z|=1$ then $g(z)=\frac{z^2}{f(z)}$ is holomorphic, $\left|\frac{z^2}{f(z)}\right|=1$ for $|z|=1$, and $g(0)=0$. Therefore $g: D\to D$ and you can apply Schwartz to $g$.

Then $\left|\frac{z^2}{f(z)}\right|\leq |z|$, which gives you $|z|\leq |f(z)|$.

We get also that $1\geq|g'(0)|=\lim_{z\to0}\left|\frac{z}{f(z)}\right|\left|\frac{2f(z)-zf'(z)}{f(z)}\right|=\frac{1}{|f'(0)|}\cdot\lim_{z\to0}\left|\frac{2-\frac{z}{f(z)}f'(z)}{1}\right|=\frac{1}{|f'(0)|}$.

Therefore $|f'(0)|\geq1.$

Comment: I know this is obvious, but why can't I say $g(z) \geq \inf g(z)$ and let $r\to 1$?

Comment: What is $r$? and you mean $|g(z)|\geq \inf |g(z)|$, no?

Comment: Yes, I mean the modulus inequality. $r$ is the radius of $D$, the disk.